# Re-bind button click event using anonymous functions - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 5 HTML buttons, in which I have bound a click event listener to each one. Each even listener is anonymous function.

Example:

```
    $('#button1').click(function(){
        //some code
    });
```

At some point in my code, I have unbound the click event listeners to stop the user from clicking any of the 5 buttons due to some event.

However, when I try to bind them again from a different file, due to some event finishing (after progress bar animation finishes), I am unable to bind them to their original state.

I know it is possible to remove the anonymous functions out of the click event listener, and when I have to rebind the button, call that function again. However, since I have 5 different buttons, doing 5 different functions, I thought it might be a bit tedious to do so.

TLDR: My question is, is there any way to re-bind a click event to a button back to its original state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding and unbinding, I will suggest you to have a `flag` whose value changes based on the condition you want to bind/unbind. Based on the flag, you can proceed with the code accordingly.

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
  if (flag) {//flag will change according to your condition
    //some code
  }
});
```

The `flag` can be a global variable which can be accessed by other functions too.

Comment: Thank you very much! I like this answer. I would up-vote as well but I don't have enough reputation unfortunately